# redirect to tab page from canvace page in facebook apps using php

Tags: facebook

i have created facebook application in which i need to redirect user from tab page to canvace page and also redirect back to tab page from canvace page...
using php
header('location:');
this command is working but it dose not directly redirect to tab page...
temporary i will redirect to facebook logo page with redirection link "Go facebook."
on clicking that like we can redirect to tab page...
Is there any solution to direct redirection to tab page from canvance page...

Answer (score 1):

Yes there's:

```
echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $page_tab_url . "'</script>");
```

This way is mentioned in the [Facebook documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/) in a couple of places.

Answer (score 0):

To get it to work in Internet Explorer I had to use following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <script>
                parent.location.href = '<?php echo url;?>';
       </script>

    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $page_tab_url . "'</script>");
```

is working well in IE,
**but NOT in** firefox and Chrome !!